# Hashem and time

Tags: time, theology

If hashem is beyond time, then how could he talk about it? Is it because he created time?

Answer (score 3):

Hashem is not bound by time, but we are. When He communicates with us, He does so according to our perception.

Answer (score -1):

because HE IS bEY6OND IT HENCE HE CAN TALK ABOUT IT HE HAS THE FULL GRASP JUST AS ONLY THE WATCHMAKER KNOWS THE WATCH

Comment: Why are you typing like that?